# UFW deny not banning

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ufw

I've recently moved our server to AWS and am having difficulty getting UFW to ban IPs, I've never had the issue when running our server locally. I've tried the typical suggestions (ordering the rules, reloading, etc.) with no success. Currently I have an IP constantly hitting asterisk and UFW doesn't seem to be banning the IP.

```
[ 1] Anywhere                   DENY IN     xx.xx.xx.xx                     
[ 5] 22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 6] 80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 7] 443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 8] 25/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 9] 465/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[10] 993                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[11] 10000:20000/tcp            ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[12] 10000:20000/udp            ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[13] 5060                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
```

I'm running ubuntu 16.04. Any suggestion as to why UFW wouldn't be blocking the IP would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't you need something like fail2ban for that?

Comment: I also use fail2ban, and there are other methods as well, but I'm more trying to determine why UFW isn't working properly.

Comment: What is the actual state of your firewall? Run `iptables -S`.